# Does "I can do better than X" mean "I can find a girlfriend/boyfriend better than X"

Tags: idioms

Does "I can do better than X" mean "I can find a girlfriend/boyfriend better than X"? Or it's applicable for other situations too (e.g. talking about someone's car).

Found in the context of this comics of xkcd:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in this case "I can do better" means "I can find a better girlfriend."  However it doesn't have to apply only to relationships.

> She can do better **than a job** where she just does tech support and never develops her own applications.
>
> My mother can do better **than a car** which breaks down every thousand miles.
>
> Fred can do better **than a friend** like me, who only calls when I need something from him.

Anyway, +1 for XKCD.  I assume you get the humor here?

Comment: @ruwhynot  Just in case you don't know:  Every XKCD comic has a "secondary" joke embedded in the title, which you can see when you mouse-over the image.  In this case it's *"And if you labeled your axes, I could tell you exactly how MUCH better."*

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. You've just opened a new world for me. Thanks!